# MouseListener event not working in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I'm creating an application in which a list of images will be displayed in JList.
Each image will be displayed as embedded in a panel. When user moves cursor over the images, images should be displayed as enlarged in another frame.

Now, I've implemented MouseListner interface over each panel displaying an event. and I've added mouseListner() over each panel.

Now, when user clicks or moves in or out of panel .. no events are occuring.

Is it because of the fact that when I'm clicking on an image, I'm actually clicking on JLabel and not on the panel directly?

What might be other cause?

Comment: An SSCCE would be very useful to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of the fact that when I'm clicking on an image, I'm actually clicking on JLabel and not on the panel directly?

You are actually clicking on the JList. A renderer is NOT a real component.

You need to add the MouseListener to the JList and then determine which rendered item was clicked by using the indexToLocation(...) method of the JList.

Edit:

Actually that should be locationToIndex(...) method of the JList. Sometimes my fingers don't type what my mind is thinking :)

Comment: how will I come to know, on which item it was clicked ??

Comment: ya. u added it later..
thanx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture mouse move events you need to implement `MouseMotionListener` instead of `MouseListener`.

Comment: but mouseExit and mouseEntered functions are defined in MouseListner interface.. they r meant to check if mouse has enterd or not right ??

Comment: No, that is defined in a MouseMotionListener, and you need to add a mouseMotionListener to your component not a mouseListener.

Comment: It is time to take the comment about the SSCCE more seriously.  We can make random suggestions about your code based upon guesses.  But most people worth listening to **don't like guessing.**